# Click at menu using accessibility id and xpath error

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation, android-testing

I'm trying to click on this menu, but I'm not picking up, there always appears an error message to the driver that the element is not interactive, I've tried with xpath, class Name and accessibility id, nothing works, any opinions?

[id and xPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5oSt.png)
[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeRZ6.png)

```
dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
dc.setCapability("platformName", "android");
dc.setCapability("appPackage", "-----------");
dc.setCapability("appActivity", "-------------------");

AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);

MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("email");
el1.sendKeys("-------");
MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("password");
el2.sendKeys("-------");

driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
Thread.sleep(1000);

MobileElement el = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("email_sign_in_button");
el.click();
driver.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[3]/android.widget.TextView[1]\n").click();
Thread.sleep(4000);

MobileElement e13 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc=\"open_drawer\"]");
e13.click();


* Element info: {Using=accessibility id, value=open_drawer}
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.FindsByAccessibilityId.findElementByAccessibilityId(FindsByAccessibilityId.java:37)
at Medições.main(Medições.java:44)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) ever, it doesn't add any value but makes your tests slower.

When you need to wait for the page to load or element to become available - go for [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits). In Selenium/Appium Java client API the class you're looking for is [WebDriverWait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

```
MobileElement e13 = (MobileElement) new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc=\"open_drawer\"]")));
```

See [Explicitly wait until visibility of an element using Android driver in Java](https://discuss.appium.io/t/explicitly-wait-until-visibility-of-an-element-using-android-driver-in-java/21314) article for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this, I'm going to change in the remaining tests, but I still can't click on the menu, do you have any idea what it might be?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options to click on the element.

- **Actions Class**

```
MobileElement e13 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='open_drawer']");
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(e13).click().build().perform();
```

---

- **JavaScripts Executor**

```
MobileElement e13 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='open_drawer']");     
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", e13);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it still does not work, giving the same error log

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it after a lot of effort using this code:

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(10,100)).moveTo(PointOption.point(200, 100)).release();
    touchAction.perform();
```

Thanks for the help